# Enable Debugging Javascript in Visual Studio (WebView Android app Xamarin)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am building a Xamarin Android webview mobile app. I have gotten to a point that I need to debug some Javascript code but I cannot get the debugger to work on the razor views in Xamarin. Not a single breakpoint is hit on the client-side during debugging.

I have tried using the below code to enable debugging of my web contents in my main activity `OnCreate` method. Link: [Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled/p/System.Boolean/) :

```
WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

I also tried using the `debugger` keyword in my script to see if I could be lucky.
But none of the above seem to help the situation.

Are there any pointers on how to enable client-side debugging in Xamarin?

Comment: You can use Chrome's Developer Tools to debug javascript :  https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

Comment: @JackZhai That documentation link above in the question is from Xamarin. I really don't understand why they provided it in the first place.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, I will have a look at it.

Comment: @Oluwafemi, Sorry for my misunderstand, the document in your link would be related to the Android WebViews debugging, like the link http://www.aptude.com/blog/entry/debugging-android-webviews-for-hybrid-mobile-applications, it also provided the different debug ways for different Android version which was also included in SushiHangover's suggestions.

Comment: @Oluwafemi, What about this issue? Would you please share the latest information about it?

Comment: No luck yet buddy.

Comment: @Oluwafemi, I didn't find better suggestion, but if possible, I suggest you discuss this issue with the Xamarin team members here: https://forums.xamarin.com/, so they could provide better solution or workaround. Or you could share a simple sample in the Xamrin supported forum, so the Xamarin members could really troubleshoot this issue with your sample. Sorry for no solution for this issue.